# Arrays split into header and source files

Tags: c++

for some bizarre reason I always forget the exact syntax of arrays. How do I create an array in the header and initialise it in the constructor? Is it possible to initialise it in the header as well as defining it?

Comment: Forgot syntax? What you really need is a good book & lookup the fundamentals.

Comment: I can't find any that tell you how to split it into header and source.

Comment: Are you looking to have a class member array? Or a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since read up on this issue a little more and it seems it is not possible: This actually hits on one of the shortcomings of the C++ language — there is no way to initialize non-static array members in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `extern` keyword to declare variables in the header, but defining in the header might lead to multiple definitions and linker errors (unless you use `static` keyword and header-guards, in which case you'd be creating separate array instances per each translation unit).

For example:

Header

```
extern int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
static int stArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {initialized static array};
```

X.CPP

```
#include the header
int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {initialize here}
... some code
int i = array[index]; //access the array initialized in X.CPP
int j = stArray[index]; //access the array initialized in X.CPP
                      //when including the header
```

Y.CPP

```
#include the header
// don't initialize
...
in some code do:
int i = array[index]; // you'll access the array initialized in X.CPP.
int j = stArray[index]; //access the array initialized in Y.CPP when
                   // including the header, not the same as in X.CPP
```

**Edit**

Re class members - they're usually defined in header files, but they're created when the class instances (objects) are created, and should be initialized in the constructor. Unless you're marking them as `static`, and then you have to define them in a CPP file somewhere (in a similar fashion to the `extern` variables).

Also, it was mentioned in the comments: global variables should not be accessed prior to `main` being called (i.e.: one global/static variable shouldn't be initialized based on the value of another global/static value). That might lead to a problem known as [Static Initialization Fiasco](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21732/).

Comment: Just be aware that this is undefined behavior if `array` is accessed _before_ main is called (by global objects construction).  You won't get a warning or error.

Comment: there's no way of having an array in a class without it being static or extern?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you COULD always use a pointer and do it dynamically...Just have to remember to clean it up with delete[].

In the header, just declare a pointer...

```
   int * x = 0;
```

And in the cpp, call new and do what you need with it.

```
   x = new int[15];
   //do stuff
   delete [] x;
```